# How can I optimize an SQL query (Using Indexes but not bitmap indexes)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, optimization, query-optimization

I have an SQL query, example:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB1 NATURAL JOIN TAB2 WHERE TAB1.COL1 = 'RED'
```

How can I optimize this query to use indexes but not bitmap indexes in Oracle?

Comment: Never use natural joins. They are very error-prone (adding columns to tables can break existing queries). Moreover the natural join is hiding the join criteria from us, which prevents us from helping. So far you should at least have an index on tab1(col1) to offer the DBMS something to work with. Please show the columns the tables are joined on. And: Must you really select all columns from both tables?

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:  This answers the original version of the question.

First, don't use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is an abomination because it does not use properly declared foreign key relationships.  It simply uses columns with the same name, and that can produce misleading results.

Second, the query is syntactically incorrect for two reasons.  First, `"Red"` is a reference to a *column*, not a string value.  Does the table have a column named `"Red"`.  The second reason is that you have a self join, so `ROW1` is ambiguous.

That rings up the larger issue.  Your query basically makes no sense at all.  You are joining the table to itself, returning duplicate columns.  What are the results?  Pretty indeterminate:

- If any column contains a `NULL` value, then no rows are returned.
- If all the rows are duplicates (with no `NULL` values), then you'll get a result set with the N^2 rows and duplicate columns, where N is the number of rows in the table.

I cannot think of any use for the query.  I see no reason to try to optimize it.

If you have a real query that you want to discuss, I would suggest that you ask another question.

Comment: @KárolyNeue . . . You should ask another question.